# How do I test email server reliability?

Tags: email, mail-server

My company rents an email host, but I just noticed sometimes an email takes around 5 hours to deliver and it's unacceptable.

I went to complain to the host, and they said they needed proof; as it just happens in random situations, it's hard to "catch" the moment.

Is there a way to test the mail delivery? Such as a program that can send an email every 15 min? Or any suggestion to get proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **or any suggestion to get proves?**

[View](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_view_full_mail_headers_in_outlook.html) the email headers on received email, they show the intermediate points through which the email passed and the date and time of processing at each point. This can prove where the delay occurs.

> SMTP defines the trace information of a message, which is also saved
>   in the header using the following two fields:[50]
>
> Received: when an SMTP server accepts a message it inserts this trace
>   record at the top of the header (last to first).

*(from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_header))*

---

> **a program which can send an email every 15 min?**

I'd use `mail` in a `cron` script on a Linux box.